# MathKernel and MathLM interaction

Tags: kernel, licensing

If one restarts MathLM on a Linux server, will that restart mathkernel as well? In other words, will restarting MathLM affect the current jobs running that use MathKernels?

Thanks.

Comment: No. If for example the MathLM server crashes, the client copies of Mathematica won't suddenly close. In other words the clients are not constantly contacting the license server for their licenses.

Comment: @Searke it contradicts my observations. It happened to me few times (two times I guess) that I lost part of my work some time after the crash of the server running MathLM. But in all these cases I was working in the frontend, not in pure MathKernel.

Comment: If the mathlm isn't restarted fast enough you might see this. I don't know what the period of check-ins would be.

Comment: You should really see my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11955/how-often-does-mathematica-contact-its-license-server/13344#13344).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that yes, it does affect the current jobs. One has to restart the jobs. The jobs just lose "connection" with the license manager. One would expect it to run as an independent process and get finished despite losing the communication with license manager. However, MathKernel does not execute the jobs and neither does it throw an error. Finally, the processes need to be killed.